# time synchronization on quectel m66

Tags: at-command, ntp, quectel

in IRAN the mobile operators can't support NITZ protocol. one of the ways that operator suggest to me is that I can use NTP protocol. when use AT+QNTP="example",example for any example QUECTEL M66 reply to me: ERROR.

when send this AT command: at+qntp?
m66 reply to me this command: +QNTP:"210.72.145.44",123

nevertheless when I send this AT command: AT+QNTP="210.72.145.44",123 again m66 reply to me: ERROR.

how can I resolve this problem in order to set NTP and synchronization time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Set AT+CMEE=2 to give more verbose error report. 2) AT+QNTP requires a packet data connection (PDN/PDP) to be established first, have you done that?

Comment: maybe just a typo, but I think "at+qntp?" should be "at+qntp=?" (see https://www.quectel.com/ProductDownload/M66.html, page 179.